# Passando variável para view e capturando

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Já tentei de várias formas capturar a variável que eu passo para a view, porém sem sucesso.

### Controlle

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $retornoDestroy = $this->qpae->find($id);

    $delete = $retornoDestroy->delete();

    //Cria uma classe vazia StdClass
    $st = new \stdClass();

    if (isset($delete)) {

        $st->message = 'Apagado com sucesso!';

        return redirect()
            ->route('qpae-listar')->with('st', $st);                       

    }       
}
```

### View

```
@if(isset($st))  
 <div id="msg" class="alert alert-sucess">                
  <p>{{$st}}</p>
 </div>
@endif
```

Caso seja deletado com sucesso, redireciono e passo junto a mensagem `$st`, contudo, não consigo fazer exibir essa mensagem na view.

Já tentei também com:

```
@if(session('st'))  
 <div id="msg" class="alert alert-sucess">                
  <p>{{session('st')}}</p>
 </div>
@endif
```

Que me retorna o erro:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (0)

```
@if(session('st'))  
 <div id="msg" class="alert alert-sucess">                
  <p>{{$st->message}}</p>
 </div>
@endif
```

> Undefined variable: st (0)

---

## Solução

### Controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $retornoDestroy = $this->qpae->find($id);

    $delete = $retornoDestroy->delete();

    //Cria uma classe vazia StdClass
    $st = new \stdClass();

    if (isset($delete)) {

        $st->message = 'Apagado com sucesso!';

        return redirect()
            ->route('qpae-listar')->with('st', $st); **with sem colchete**                       

    }       
}
```

### View

```
@if(session('st'))  
 <div id="msg" class="alert alert-success">                
  {{ session()->get('st')->message }}
 </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Seu `$st` é um objeto, tente acessar um atributo dele como `$st->message`

Comment: Já tentei também, sem sucesso. Undefined variable: st (0)

Comment: Qual a versão do laravel está usando? Tente passar o parametro para a view alterando para `->with(['st', $st]);`

Comment: Versão 5.8.2. Tentei dessa forma `->with(['st', $st]);` não recebo mais erros na view, porém a mensagem ainda não aparece.

Comment: Na view você mostra a mensagem dessa forma: `{{ session()->get( 'st' )->message }}`

Comment: Deu certo! Mostrei usando: `{{ session()->get( 'st' )->message }}` e tive que retirar os colchetes de `->with(['st', $st]);` ficando `->with('st', $st);`

Comment: Poste então como solução do seu post!

Comment: Uma dica: pra mensagens desse tipo você pode usar o Flash Data do laravel.